# Layer control in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, shortcode, mapbox

I'm a newbee in mapbox... I have succesfully installed Mapbox plugin in Worpress and published some maps on.... but I need to add control layers to this embedded maps with short codes...

I have tried this shortcodes but i don't find information about to add layer controls

```
Mapa DEM, Santiago, CL
[mapbox width=950 height=400 z=12 layers=amoya.gia7p661 options=shareControl:false]

Mapa Imágen Satelital, Chuquicamata, CL
[mapbox width=950 height=400 z=12 layers=amoya.giabf0d1]

Mapa Urbano: Ciudad de México, MX
[mapbox width=950 height=400 z=12 layers=amoya.giab13c8]
```

can anyone help me... with some examples...

Here is my website... http://explorations.cl/webmapping-services/

Regards from Chile

Renix

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe the Mapbox plugin for Wordpress is currently supported, however I recommend the [Raw HTML](http://wordpress.org/plugins/raw-html/) plugin which allows you to write HTML/CSS/JS in your posts without Wordpress formatting it. Additionally you'll be able to use all of [the examples show on mapbox.com](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/) and learn more JavaScript in the process.